# Update Table Column using Combobox or dropdown

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

Hi I'm trying to update a column using a Combobox, What I'm trying to do is when you select the year it updates the user column with that year, the concept it to have multiple years with different users I would really love to hear if you have a different way to solve this I'm using MVC and devexpress

What I have done so far is I have the year id in both tables with a foreign key attached which is working now I want to switch between years or id's to the whole app so they can enter multiple years of data and filter using the dropdown instead of regular devexpress filters,

[image]

--------------------------------------------- Edit 
Should been more specific here is my database structure, 
[image]

So what I have so far is the data under benefits table change with the selected year table when member year id = member benefits id, so what I'm trying to do is just update the member id when you select a different year so I can add more benefits to the same user. 
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure MVC flow, you probably want to refresh the page if the select value is changed.

```
public ActionResult GetData(int year)
{
    //DB query to get the data from the year
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then add javascript / JQuery to refresh the page

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#selectBox').on('change', function() {
        var year = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = "/Admin/GetData?year=" + year;
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, its kind of different than what I'm looking for, I added more details to my question, appreciate the help

Comment: Still a bit confused here, so you already have all the data from every year in your view correct? You just want to display the data according to the selected dropdownlist, without going back to controller and db query, is this correct?

Comment: So I have a View in which I have rendered a <select> box and you want upon changing the value of this select box by the user to invoke a Controller Action passing the newly selected value to the server so that it can perform some processing.

Comment: I never use devexpress before, but if you use pure MVC flow (without the help of javascript / jquery / angularjs / etc...). You have to redirect to controller, passing the parameter, then redirect back to the view with the view model to be displayed in the view.